# Trying to reverse order of four verses in javascript

Tags: javascript, reverse, console.log

I´m trying to write the necessary statements to print the four verses of the Programmer's Lament but in reverse order. I´m trying to learn more about code and doing some exercises, the verses are ones below:

> I really hate this damned machine
>
> I wish that they would sell it.
>
> It never does quite what I want
>
> But only what I tell it.

They say that I have to use console.log for each one of the lines. I already try several ways but none is correct.

These lines were the closest I got, but only the last line changed, as it gives me an error when creating another string

```
console.log('I really hate this damned machine');
console.log('It never does quite what I want');
console.log('I wish that they would sell it');
console.log('But only what I tell it');

let string = "I really hate this damned machine It never does quite what I want I wish that they would sell it But only what I tell it";

let reversed = [...string].reverse().join("");
console.log(reversed);
```

Can anyone help me with this? Maybe it is easy but I´m a junior on this :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If starting with a punctuated string, split it on the ". " delimiter to get an array of each sentence. reverse the array of sentences, then join to get back to a string.

```js
let string = "I really hate this damned machine. It never does quite what I want. I wish that they would sell it. But only what I tell it";
let array = string.split(". ");
let reversed = array.reverse().join(".\n");
console.log(reversed + '.');
```

Comment: There is a little cheating with the changed punctuation of the originally phrased *lament*. According to the OP's citation there is a multiline string with just two period characters (once every 2nd line).

Comment: @PeterSeliger, the OP's description of the input is ambiguous.  I'd say more likely that it's punctuation delimited than newline delimited. Or maybe it's a 50/50 probability?  Would you characterize choosing the alternative interpretation and copying the rest of someone else's answer as a cheat, also?

Comment: No need to turn it into a competition. And a look at both answer's timestamps fortunately exculpates me from being a copy cat. Writing my answer with all the documentation links took me something like 30 minutes.

Comment: @PeterSeliger - you're right, I'm rubbing my eyes now because I saw myself alone on this post for a long time.  I must have missed a reload.  I withdraw my snarky third sentence with apologies.  It's a good answer

Comment: @PeterSeliger - Just got back here while closing up tabs.  Now I'm confused again, because the timestamps 18:56:29Z for mine and 19:07:28Z for yours match my prior understanding. Not aiming to reopen a silly argument, just confused.

Answer (score 0):

- Start with a multiline string provided maybe as [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like ...

  ```
  `I really hate this damned machine
  I wish that they would sell it.
  It never does quite what I want
  But only what I tell it.`
  ```
- [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) multiline string with the help of a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) at any [new line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#using_regular_expression_to_split_lines_with_different_line_endingsends_of_lineline_breaks) (`\n`) into an array.
- [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the array.
- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the reversed array again ... of cause with new line / `\n`.

```
`I really hate this damned machine
I wish that they would sell it.
It never does quite what I want
But only what I tell it.`.split(/\n/).reverse().join('\n');
```

```js
// - use backticks which enclose a multiline string.
//   - [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals]
const lament = `I really hate this damned machine
I wish that they would sell it.
It never does quite what I want
But only what I tell it.`;

// log to prove it is a multiline string.
console.log({ lament });

// - split mulitline string with the help of a
//   regular expression at any new line (`\n`)
//   into an array.
//   - [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split]
//   - [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp]
//   - [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#using_regular_expression_to_split_lines_with_different_line_endingsends_of_lineline_breaks]
console.log(
  'lament.split(/\\n/) ...',

  lament.split(/\n/)
);

// - reverse the array
//   - [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse]
console.log(
  'lament.split(/\\n/).reverse() ...',

  lament.split(/\n/).reverse()
);

// - join the reversed array
//   - [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join]
console.log(
  'lament.split(/\\n/).reverse().join(\'\\n\') ...\n',

  lament.split(/\n/).reverse().join('\n')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit** in order to solve the OP's original task*

> I really hate this damned machine
>
> I wish that they would sell it.
>
> It never does quite what I want
>
> But only what I tell it.
>
> > They say that I have to use console.log for each one of the lines. I already try several ways but none is correct.

```js
`I really hate this damned machine
I wish that they would sell it.
It never does quite what I want
But only what I tell it.`
 .split(/\n/)
 .reverse()
 .forEach(line => console.log(line));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but keeps saying that >>>>Code is incorrect
You need exactly one console.log() statement in your code for each verse you want to print

Comment: `.forEach(line => console.log(line));` ... does *"...exactly one console.log() statement in your code for each verse you want to print"*

Comment: Ya when I run here your example it works, but on their platform the error is ">>>>Code is incorrect
You need exactly one console.log() statement in your code for each verse you want to print
split is not defined" really no ideia what they want, because it seems possible in different ways, but I think their platform only accepts one?!! It is tricky

Comment: If none of the until now provided answers, approaches, hints, could not help solving the task, then either the OP's description of the problem is not that comprehensibly provided in order to be fully understood by the audience or the same accounts for the website which the OP does use. Maybe the OP tries to describe in four short clear sentences all the requirements and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the problem into the following

1. How to have a multiline text in Javascript
2. Split the lines
3. Reverse the lines
4. Join them back

How to have a multiline text? You can have it using backticks

[Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

`I really hate this damned machine

I wish that they would sell it.

It never does quite what I want

But only what I tell it.`

```js
function reverseVerse(verse){

   // splitting the lines based on the new line. this provides an array

let lines = verse.split("\n")

// reversing the lines again

let reversedLines = lines.reverse().join("\n")
console.log(reversedLines)

}

let verse = `I really hate this damned machine

I wish that they would sell it.

It never does quite what I want

But only what I tell it.`


reverseVerse(verse)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but it keeps saying that ">>>>Code is incorrect
You need exactly one console.log() statement in your code for each verse you want to print"

Comment: Raquel, your requirement is not too clear, but guess only a single console.log is allowed. Converted to a function. If this is not acceptable, please provide the things allowed to use for achieving the desired output